# php replace problem

Tags: php, replace

there are some url, like `11162_sport.html`, `11451_sport.html`, `11245_sport.html` or `231sport.html`,
I want when the url like `XXXXX_sport.html` then replace them into `11162_football.html`, `11451_football.html`, `11245_football.html`, and `231sport.html` has no change.

how to replace them, `$newurl = preg_replace("_sport.html","_football.html",$url)`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do `$newurl = str_replace("_sport.html", "_football.html", $url);`
This is faster than doing a `preg_replace()` and more accurant.

see [the manual on str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for such simple replacement.

Answer (score 1):

If it *must* be regular expressions, do:

```
preg_replace('/_sport\.html$/', '_football.html', $url);
```

`str_replace()` would indeterminately replace *all* occurences of `sport.html` whereas a regular expression with an end-of-line marker (`$`) will only replace the pattern at the end of the URL.

The dot needs to be escaped because it would match any character (except new-lines).